# What exactyle is ownerState in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, react-props, material-components

I clone a Material-dashboard repository from gitHub to practice the Material UI library. when i was looking the code I found the **ownerState** prop and i'm confuse that is it custom prop or provided by Material UI library I do a research on it and I think that it is object which contain all props we can pass through any MUI Component but I'm not exactly sure what exactly is ?

Here is my custom component...

[image: Here is my custom component...]

There we pass object to ownerState

[image: There ownerState prop is used]

and here the prop is used

[image: and here the prop is used]

Answer (score 6):

According to [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/customization/unstyled-components/#overriding-the-unstyled-components-slots) it is:

> The ownerState prop is a combination of public props that you pass to the component + internal state of the component.

You can read more [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/#what-problems-does-it-solve).